# How to make this function process in constant time?

Tags: c#, time-complexity

I need to find the n-th term of this infinite series: 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4...

Can you give me a constant time function for this task?

```
int i = 1;
while(true)
{
   if(i = n)
      //do things and exit the loop

   i++;
}
```

I think this isn`t going to be a constant time function...

Comment: `return x[n - 1];` Constant time enough for you?

Comment: To clarify, does the array always contain one "1", two "2"s, three "3"s, etc?

Comment: Oooh, you want the nth *unique* term?

Comment: I think we are all latching on to the "array" part of this, which isn't his question. I think the question is, "how can I determine the n-th term of a sequence of numbers that follow this pattern in O(1) time?"

Comment: I don`t know the length of the array or anything. I just know the pattern of the array (example: the array would have 1 item with value 1, 2 items with value 2, 3i with v 3, ... , 10 i with v 10)

Comment: Are you looking for the _position_ of the nth unique therm?  Or the term itself?

Comment: the term itself, but i don`t know the hole array, just the pattern, for example the 100 term of the sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given my understanding of the problem, this is more of a math problem than a programming one.

If the problem is:

**Given an infinite series that consists of 1 copy of 1, 2 copies of 2, 3 copies of 3... n copies of n, what is the kth value in this series?**

Now the first clue when approaching this problem is that there are 1 + 2 + 3... + n values before the first occurance of n + 1. Specifically there are (sum of the first n numbers) values before n+1, or (n)(n-1)/2.

Now set (n)(n-1)/2 = k. Multiply out and rationalize to n^2 - n - 2k = 0. Solve using quadratic equation, you get n = (1 + sqrt(1+8k))/2. The floor of this gives you how many full copies of n there are before, and happily, given zero based indexing, the floor gives you the value at the kth point in the array.

That means your final answer in c# is

`return (int) Math.Floor((1 + Math.Sqrt(1 + 8 * k)) / 2);`

Given non zero based indexing,

`return (int) Math.Floor((1 + Math.Sqrt(-7 + 8 * k)) / 2);`

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

After reading more comments, it appears I misunderstood the question.

If you want to find the item at `n`th position an *array* in constant time, then the answer is trivial: `x[n]`, because array access is constant time.  However, if for some reason you were using some container where access time is not constant (e.g. linked list), or did not want to look up value in the array, you'd have to use the [arithmetic series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html) formulas to find the answer.

Arithmetic series tells us that the position `n` of the `i`th unique item would be

```
n = i * (i - 1) / 2
```

So we just need to solve for `i`.  Using quadratic formula, and discarding the nonsensical negative option, we get:

```
i = Math.Floor( (1 + Math.Sqrt(1 + 8 * n)) / 2)
```

**Original Response**

I'm assuming you're looking for the *position* of the nth *unique* term, because otherwise the problem is trivial.

Sounds like the first occurrence of the nth unique term should follow [arithmetic series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html).  I.e. the position of nth unique term would be:

```
n * (n - 1) / 2
```

Comment: +1 Assuming the values always follow that pattern, and by "term" he meant value, then yes this works beautifully

Comment: if he wants the nth unique term of the given series, than the answer is `return n;`...

Comment: no i want to know what value is at index nth without knowing the hole array, just the pattern of the array

Comment: @HansZ Only because the array starts at 1. Following the same pattern starting at any arbitrary number makes more a more interesting question

Comment: Are you looking to do that without actually looking up in the array?  Because array access is constant time.

Comment: @ngmiceli `return n + k - 1; //k is the starting number`

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static long Foo(long index)
        {
            if (index < 0)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }

            long nowNum = 0;
            long nowIndex = 0;
            do
            {
                nowIndex += nowNum;
                nowNum++;
            } while (nowIndex < index);
            return nowNum;
        }
```